# How can I change organization name from workspace in Jenkins artifactory plugin

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I have setup a build chain successfully with Gradle, Jenkins and Artifactory. I push them using the default artifact name:

```
Artifact pattern = [organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

When I look in artifact it resolves [organisation] to "workspace" I would like to use a different name (company name) for this folder, how do I change this without changing the pattern? So How can I have Jenkins resolve the correct orginization? Should I edit my build.gradle? Or is this some other setting?

Comment: Who is resolving Gradle/Jenkins? is this the Jenkins workspace folder?

Comment: I believe that would be the artifactory plugin in Jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to fix this I added:

```
group = "someName"
```

to my build.gradle